# Who can tell me the name of this plant

Tags: identification, houseplants

I bought this plant in aldis and it does not say what type of plant it is, please help![image][image]

Answer (score 4):

It is Fatsia japonica,commonly called castor oil plant. It is fully hardy out of doors in the UK and in some areas of the USA, but can be used as a houseplant. Its ultimate height and spread is about 10 feet or  more in the ground outdoors - it will do well in a pot for a number of years, provided you give it a larger pot every couple of years. It tolerates relatively low light situations quite well indoors and is best kept out of direct sunlight. Further information here https://www.thespruce.com/growing-fatsia-japonica-inside-1902617